# javascript window.location pathname

Tags: javascript

i have a quiz script and the problem is it's leading to one answer in file html format in my website directory in cpanel and i want to have random answers. how can i add more html result files and have window.location lead to random answers? this is my code

```
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    shared(value);
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;

    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    if(value>= STRONG.share){
      window.location="/result.html";
```

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Please can you explain how to use it on my code. I tried it but it didn't work. Thank you